# How to control EF Insert into database?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have 3 tables `Goods`, `Producer`, `Categories`. `Producer` and `Categories` have a one-to-many relationship with `Goods`, and I have a generic insert method, code shown below.

The problem is that when I'm trying to insert a list of goods, first good is added correctly, but if the next one has a category with same id, it's throwing an exception about primary key.

But I want to control insert something like, checking every time before insert tables `Categories` and `Producer` and if row already exists, just update it for example or skip.

Code with models and my generic insert here:

```
public class Good
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Producer Producer { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id + "/" + Name + "/" + Price + "/" + Category.Name + "/" + Producer.Name + "/" + Producer.Country;
    }
}

public class Producer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Good> Goods { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id + "/" + Name + "/" + Country;
    }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Good> Goods { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id + "/" + Name;
    }
}

public void AddList(List<T> collection, DbContext GoodsContext)
{
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            GoodsContext.Set<T>().Add(item);
            GoodsContext.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with the newly released [EntityGraphOperations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityGraphOperations/) for Entity Framework Code First. And I have published it in the [github](https://github.com/FarhadJabiyev/EntityGraphOperations), [code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1131322/Automatically-Define-the-State-of-All-Entities-in) and [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityGraphOperations/). With the help of `InsertOrUpdateGraph` method, it will automatically set your entities as `Added` or `Modified`.

```
 foreach (var item in collection)
 {
        // This will set the state of the main entity and all of it's navigational 
        // properties as `Added` or `Modified`.
        GoodsContext.InsertOrUpdateGraph(item);
        GoodsContext.SaveChanges();

        GoodsContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;
 }
```

You can read [my article on Code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1131322/Automatically-Define-the-State-of-All-Entities-in) with a step-by-step demonstration and a sample project is ready for downloading.

Comment: Can you explain how should looks like an InsertOrUpdateGraph for my solution?I created mappings and added graph operations but still cant how insertorupdate should looks like.Thanks.

Comment: @Demsaas You must add `using EntityGraphOperations;` You can download and check the sample project from codeproejct.

Comment: Okay,its adding first one the way as you said and on second one there is exception:The sequence does not contain the corresponding element;

Comment: Can you explain why when im trying to add another Good with the Category that already exist its throwing exception that:The sequence does not contain the corresponding element??

Comment: @Demsaas Could you please show me your code? Because, it mustn't throw exceptoin. In what part does it throw?

Comment: foreach (var item in collection)
 {
       // This will set the state of the main entity and all of it's navigational 
       // properties as `Added` or `Modified`.
       GoodsContext.InsertOrUpdateGraph(item);
       GoodsContext.SaveChanges();
 }

Comment: the same,as you sended,it throw on first item of collection.                     {10/ Mon1 /2,76/Technique/Sony/Korea}                                            {13/ Mon2 /452,76/Technique/Sony/China} as you can see i have same Category on second one-Sony as i understood it shouldnt just add it to category but producer and good should be added,but its throwing exception.

Comment: *throws on second item of collection

Comment: @Demsaas You must create new context after saving changes for solving this problem.

Comment: What do you mean?Just after saving changes add this line?GoodsContext newcont = new GoodsContext(); It's doesnt help,or i just didnt get what you meant.

Comment: Okay when im doing smthin like:                      cont.InsertOrUpdateGraph(items[0]);
                cont.SaveChanges();
                GoodsContext newcont = new GoodsContext();
                newcont.InsertOrUpdateGraph(items[1]);
                newcont.SaveChanges(); 
It works good,but how should i use it in a foreach,should i create every time new context for next object?

Comment: @Demsaas If you want to use this library, then unfortunately yes. I can update this library with the feature you want. But, for know it won't support such feature. This library will automatically define the states of all entities. And it is really helpful.

Comment: can you try to update it,because its looks not good that i need to create such a many context for every item in a list,if list is such a big it will look like a disaster,thanks.

Comment: @Demsaas Then you can detach current entity and continue. I have updated my answer.